# why my ftp log is showing such error of anonymous logging with my server ip as client

Tags: linux

I have my ftp in my organisation . access by various branches on remote. why i'm getting such log in my ftp server (vsftpd) . as anonymous logging is not enable .and also getting the ip of my ftp server on log .plz check the screenshot and reply . what may be reasons. why my server ip is reflect on log. it should me client ip on log. my ftp server ip is 10.1.5.20 given on

```
Sat May 24 11:21:05 2014 [pid 15245] CONNECT: Client "10.1.5.20"
Sat May 24 11:21:07 2014 [pid 15244] [anonymous] FAIL LOGIN: Client "10.1.5.20"
Sat May 24 11:21:08 2014 [pid 15247] CONNECT: Client "10.1.5.20"
Sat May 24 11:21:11 2014 [pid 15246] [anonymous] FAIL LOGIN: Client "10.1.5.20"
Sat May 24 11:21:12 2014 [pid 15249] CONNECT: Client "10.1.5.20"
Sat May 24 11:21:14 2014 [pid 15248] [anonymous] FAIL LOGIN: Client "10.1.5.20"
Sat May 24 11:21:15 2014 [pid 15251] CONNECT: Client "10.1.5.20"
Sat May 24 11:21:18 2014 [pid 15250] [anonymous] FAIL LOGIN: Client "10.1.5.20"
Sat May 24 11:21:19 2014 [pid 15255] CONNECT: Client "10.1.5.20"
Sat May 24 11:21:22 2014 [pid 15254] [anonymous] FAIL LOGIN: Client "10.1.5.20"
Sat May 24 11:21:23 2014 [pid 15257] CONNECT: Client "10.1.5.20"
Sat May 24 11:21:30 2014 [pid 15256] [anonymous] FAIL LOGIN: Client "10.1.5.20"
Sat May 24 11:21:31 2014 [pid 15259] CONNECT: Client "10.1.5.20"
Sat May 24 11:21:38 2014 [pid 15258] [anonymous] FAIL LOGIN: Client "10.1.5.20"
Sat May 24 11:21:39 2014 [pid 15261] CONNECT: Client "10.1.5.20"
Sat May 24 11:21:42 2014 [pid 15260] [anonymous] FAIL LOGIN: Client "10.1.5.20"
Sat May 24 11:21:43 2014 [pid 15263] CONNECT: Client "10.1.5.20"
Sat May 24 11:21:49 2014 [pid 15262] [anonymous] FAIL LOGIN: Client "10.1.5.20"
Sat May 24 11:21:50 2014 [pid 15265] CONNECT: Client "10.1.5.20"
Sat May 24 11:21:58 2014 [pid 15264] [anonymous] FAIL LOGIN: Client "10.1.5.20
```